# ActiveRecord complex SQL statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Can AR manage complex statements such as the following?

```
SELECT COUNT(P2.emp) AS indentation, P1.emp
FROM Personnel AS P1, Personnel AS P2
WHERE P1.lft BETWEEN P2.lft AND P2.rgt
GROUP BY P1.emp
ORDER BY P1.lft;
```

From: http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html

My variation of the SQL is:

```
SELECT COUNT(R2.name) AS indentation, R1.name FROM Regions AS R1, Regions AS R2 WHERE R1.lft BETWEEN R2.lft AND R2.rgt GROUP BY R1.name ORDER BY R1.lft
```

I have located the following but have no idea how to link it all together.

```
.count(R2.name)
.where(R1.lft: R2.lft..R2.rgt)
.group("R1.name")
.order("R1.lft")
```

Comment: `.where('R1.lft BETWEEN R2.lft AND R2.rgt')
.group("R1.name")
.order("R1.lft").select('COUNT(P2.emp) AS indentation, P1.emp')` NOT TESTED. But shall work

Comment: R1 and R2 are aliases for the Resource table. I cannot understand where in your SQL it has any link to the Resource table?

Comment: What is your question again ? Which part you dont understand ?

Comment: What I don't understand is how the SQL above can be achieved in ActiveRecord. I can identify a few of the components as listed above however cannot determine how it can be strung together for use in Rails. i.e.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql

Comment: Have you tested my code ?

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I cannot understand how to implement it  as it refers to R1 & R2 which are alias's of the Regions table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  All of the SQL keywords you use, including the implied join should be documented in the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) Guide.  Let me know if you find any that aren't.

For the `BETWEEN` you *can* use ruby's `Range` object, but you may want to use explicit comparison operators.  It's a matter of personal style, I think.

Once you've learned how to construct these queries by hand, check out gems like [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) which can construct them for you.